# MILP: Minimizing $|Ax-b|$ with at most 5 x variables being non-zero

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a $m \times n$ matrix $A$, where $n$ is very large and $ n>m$ (underdetermined), and $b$ is $m \times 1$  matrix. I want to minimize $|Ax-b|$, but at most $5$ $x_i$ can be non-zero. Other constraints are that $\sum x_i=1$ and $x_i\geq 0$. So I have set up a mixed interger linear program:

$$\min \sum z_i$$
s.t.
$$Ax-b\leq z$$
$$b-Ax\leq z$$
$$\sum x_i=1$$
$$y_i \in\{0,1\}$$
$$\sum y_i=5$$
$$0\leq x_i\leq y_i$$

I'm absolutely clueless as to how to put this into MatLab. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formulation is correct (try running it with $\sum y_i=1$ as a test, that should be faster). You could try a better solver such as cplex or gurobi. Better solvers benefit from using the formulation $Ax+b = z^+ - z^i$ for absolute values (with $z$ nonnegative) due to increased sparsity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me), it would be

```
x = sdpvar(n,1);
z = sdpvar(m,1);
y = binvar(n,1);
Model = [-z <= A*x-b <= z, sum(x) == 1, x >= 0, sum(y)==5, 0<=x<=y];
Objective = sum(z);
optimize(Model,objective)
value(x)
```

If you have an integer solver installed, such as intlinprog, it will automatically be used. If you want to see what the intlinprog model looks like to reverse engineer, you can use the command export. As mentioned above though, if you really have a large problem, you would benefit from a better solver such as cplex, gurobi or mosek (all still available via via YALMIP and the same code)

Having said that, the lazy person would let the modelling layer do all the modelling

```
Objective = norm(A*x-b,1);
Model = [nnz(x) <= 5, 0 <= x <= 1];
optimize(Model,objective)
```

As asked about in the comments, generate many solutions

```
x = sdpvar(n,1);
z = sdpvar(m,1);
y = binvar(n,1);
Model = [-z <= A*x-b <= z, sum(x) == 1, x >= 0, sum(y)==5, 0<=x<=y];
Objective = sum(z);
result = optimize(Model,Objective);
Model = [Model, Objective <= value(Objective)];
while result.problem == 0
 Model = [Model, exclude(y,value(y))]  
 result = optimize(Model,Objective);
 value(x)      
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: I'm looking to find all optimal solutions and I've attempted to do it by using a for loop and adding the constraint `sum(abs(ys(:,1:(i-1))-repmat(y,1,i-1)))>=ones(1,i-1)`, where ys is the saved y-values of each iteration. It worked but when I get to the 18th iteration, I get a memory error. Is there a better or more efficient way to finding all optimal solutions?

Comment: No, there is no simple way to enumerate all optimal solutions. BTW, what you are doing can be accomplished by adding exclude(y,ys) to the model

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't seem to use the exclude function to exclude all previous solutions due to dimension mismatch, I'm only able to exclude the last calculated solution.

Comment: You add them repeatedly. See updated example

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is "How to put it into Matlab" then you can start here https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html

Consider using a modeling tool such as https://yalmip.github.io/

You may want to get yourself a specialized mixed-integer solver though if your problems get large.

Comment: Thanks, I've used a problem-based solver (https://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-basics-problem-based.html) instead, as I couldn't figure out how to work in my constraints to the solution based solver you recommended. I believe I've correctly formulated the program/model above but it's unable to solve (computes for a very long time), which leads me to think that my program/model is incorrect, most likely how I constraint x by y.

Comment: Your binary constraints look OK, it is a standard technique. It is more likely that the MIP solver in Matlab takes a lot of time.